# C# - LinQ - Read text files, group by first column and order by last column?

Tags: c#, linq

hi have a text files that contains 3 columns something like this:

```
contract1;pdf1;63
contract1;pdf2;5
contract1;pdf3;2
contract1;pdf4;00
contract2;pdf1;2
contract2;pdf2;30
contract2;pdf3;5
contract2;pdf4;80
```

now, i want to write those information into another text files ,and the output will be order put for first the records with the last column in "2,5", something like this:

```
contract1;pdf3;2
contract1;pdf2;5
contract1;pdf1;63
contract1;pdf4;00
contract2;pdf1;2
contract2;pdf3;5
contract2;pdf2;30
contract2;pdf4;80
```

how can i do?
thanks

Comment: I would start by reading https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/getting-started/. Then https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netcore-3.1 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.thenby?view=netcore-3.1.

Comment: Ahm. Your data is different. In the first sample you have a row `contract1;pdf1;63` and `contract1;pdf3;2` in the second you have `contract1;pdf1;2` and `contract1;pdf3;63` So the pdf1 und pdf3 switched their value. Why?

Comment: Such method should get you started: `File.ReadAllLines("Path to file").Select(line => line.Split(";"));` - this will return you array of arrays, where each element represents single cell from CSV file.

Comment: Please re-write the sentence starting "now, i want to write" to be clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ to group and sort the lines after reading, then put them back together:

```
var output = File.ReadAllLines(@"path-to-file")
                 .Select(s => s.Split(';'))
                 .GroupBy(s => s[0])
                 .SelectMany(sg => sg.OrderBy(s => s[2] == "2" ? "-" : s[2] == "5" ? "+" : s[2]).Select(sg => String.Join(";", sg)));
```

Then just write them to a file.

Comment: this is perfect for me!! thanks, you are a top programmer! many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to write your program for you, but I would recommend this library for reading and writing delimited files:
https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/getting-started/

When you new up the reader make sure to specify your semi-colon delimiter:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader("path\\to\\input_file.csv"))
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
{
    csv.Configuration.Delimiter = ";";
    var records = csv.GetRecords<Row>();
    // manipulate the data as needed here
}
```

Your "Row" class (choose a more appropriate name for clarity) will specify the schema of the flat file. It sounds like you don't have headers? If not, you can specify the Order of each item.

```
public class Row
{
    [Index(1)]
    public string MyValue1 { get; set; }
    [Index(2)]
    public string MyValue2 { get; set; }
}
```

After reading the data in, you can manipulate it as needed. If the output format is different from the input format, you should convert the input class into an output class. You can use the Automapper library if you would like. However, for a simple project I would suggest to just manually convert the input class into the output class.

Lastly, write the data back out:

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter("path\\to\\output_file.csv"))
using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
{    
    csv.WriteRecords(records);
}
```